# Android: dlopen() returing daglling pointer for 64 bit architecture

Tags: android, c, linux, x86-64, dlopen

I have build my App for 32 and 64 architecture by using

```
APP_ABI := x86_64 x86 armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
```

I am doing `dlopen()` in JNI side. For 32 bit arch `dlopen()` working fine and returning a valid void pointer.
I am able to type cast this pointer in `struct soinfo`. dump of `dlopen()` for 32 bit is below.

```
libjavacore.so\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\F0۱\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0۱\00\80\00\00\00\00\00\D0C߱\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F4\83\F5\B4\00\00@\A8ܱH\F1۱ \00\00\E6\00\00$jܱHrܱ\00\00\00\00\A0\ADܱ\80\00\00\E0}ܱ\F8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\ACC߱\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A6ޱ\91\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0۱\A4\82\F5\B4\D0C߱\F8\F4d\ADx\DFԵ\00\00\00\00\F0۱\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B3\00\00\A3\00\00\E4OӶ\ACp汴y汴y\E6\B1\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00tJ\00\00libmedia_jni.so\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\82\AD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\82\AD\00\D0\00\00\00\00\00ܰ\85\AD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00D\85\F5\B4\00\00@\E8<\82\ADH\82\AD  \00\00\BA\00\00\9C͂\AD\C0Ղ\AD\00\00\00\00\80\83\AD\00\00\A8䂭{\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Ȱ\85\AD\00\00\00С\85\AD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\ۄ\ADk\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\82\AD\F4\83\F5\B4ܰ\85\ADH\F6d\ADH\86\F5\B4\00\00\00\00\00\82\AD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B3\00\00\B3\00\00\BCp\E6\B1\FCq\E6\B1\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\AC\90\00\00libexif.so\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\004@\AD   \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\AD\00\C0\00\00\00\00\00\E4쁭\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\94\86\F5\B4\00\00@\BCL\AD\8CA\AD\83\00\00\00\B3\00\00\00\88Z\AD\94\\AD\00\00\00\00Ȥ\AD\85\00\00\00`_\AD\AD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0쁭\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00D[\80\AD\89\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\ADD\85\F5\B4\E4쁭\F8\84\F5\B4\98\87\F5\B4\00\00\00\00@\AD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B3\00\00x\00\00r\E6\B1\r\E6\B1q\E6\B1q\E6\B1\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

But for 64 arch `dlopen()` is not returning a valid pointer. And I am not able to type cast it into `struct soinfo`. below is the `dlopen()` dump for 64 bit

```
@\F0hn\FC\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0hn\FC\00\00\00p\00\00\00\00\00(on\FC\00\00\98\9D[t\FC\00\00A\00\00@\00\00\00\00h9in\FC\00\00\88\F2hn\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`jn\FC\00\00\8D\00\00\00\00\00\00p\95in\FC\00\00\AA\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00(on\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0hn\FC\00\00Pԉt\FC\00\00(on\FC\00\00p\9E[t\FC\00\00\90\9A[t\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0hn\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00#pt\FC\00\00X"pt\FC\00\00/pt\FC\00\00/pt\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00P\00\00\00\00\00\00\83\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\8Ain\FC\00\00<\83in\FC\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\90\89in\FC\00\00\A8\9B[t\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\859in\FC\00\001\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Pԉt\FC\00\00\8Fin\FC\00\00\F4\94in\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\95in\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00'\00\00\00\00\00\00@`?i\FC\00\00    \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`?i\FC\00\00\00\A0\00\00\00\00\00\F8\ACGi\FC\00\00\00\B8l\FC\00\00A\00\00@\00\00\00\00\D8\C6?i\FC\00\00\88b?i\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00-Ai\FC\00\00\A2\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0\91@i\FC\00\00w\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ЬGi\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\80~Gi\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`?i\FC\00\00\D0ԉt\FC\00\00\F8\ACGi\FC\00\00\E0\00\B8l\FC\00\00\80\9C[t\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`?i\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00H!pt\FC\00\00\98&pt\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\AF\00\00\00\00\00\00   \00\00\00\00\00\00\F8w@i\FC\00\00\9Cx@i\FC\00\00?\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8u@i\FC\00\00\98\9D[t\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F5\C6?i\FC\00\001\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0ԉt\FC\00\00T\89@i\FC\00\00\B0\91@i\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00̑@i\FC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00'\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

Is there any other way to do `dlopen()` for 64 bit architecture. 
I have also go through Android `binoic` source code of `Android 6` but did not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `dlopen` is an opaque handle that can be represented in type `void *`. There is no reason to think you should be able to dereference it. If bionic supports them, `dlinfo` or `dl_iterate_phdr` might be able to get you the info you want.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  Actually i want to `hook` some library function of that `.so`. and I am able to do that for 32 bit. by the help of http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-hacking-hooking-system.html 

but for 64 bit `dlopen()` in android does not return any void  pointer  to which i can type cast in `struct soinfo`  that why i am calling it as daglling pointer

Comment: i have also tried with these `dl_iterate_phdr` function but by using this  i am not able to find 'struct soinfo` pointer because for further calculation i need  `symtab_` variable of `struct soinfo`